# Why does my os.getcwd() change between two different files at the same location?

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

So I noticed that when I run the `os.path.getcwd()` in a `.ipynb` file and a `.py` file at the same location, I get different results.

The `.ipynb` file returns a path at the same level as the `.ipynb` file. While the `.py` file returns the path, one level above its location.

For instance, the `os.path.getcwd()` called in my `.py` file might return:

```
C:\...\parent
```

while the same call in `.ipynb` saved in the same location returns:

```
C:\...\parent\child
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` does not give you the path where `.ipynb` and `.py` are located. It gives you the path from where it was executed.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, I think the .py file is running from where I initiate my IDE. Just tested by initiating my IDE at a lower file level where the .py file is saved and it displayed that path.
EDIT:



I got it backwards... my .py file displays the parent and my .ipynb displays the child.

But when I run my .py script it's run in the child. Even the terminal's file-path shows the child. So why would it go up a level?

Comment: Exactly the argumentation does not change. It is where you were when you executed your program and not where the code is located. If you launch your IDE or IPython Notebook in a given location, say, A, but your .py, .ipynb are in, say, B, the command will give you A. This is the definition of CWD, i.e., the directory where you are currently working.